# Any email notification for google cloud services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been searching around in the app engine's dashboard for a way to receive any kind of notification when a quota limit is reached, but I can't find anything. I know app engine throws relevant exceptions when a limit is breached and so I considered catching these and sending emails when it happens. However in this instance this would result in an unwieldy amount of emails.

I have a hard time believing there is not way to get a email alert when the billing limit has been reached...

Comment: Hi! There is indeed nothing automated to do such a thing. The only way I can think to get something like that would be to keep an internal count of how often you hit the quota since the last reset and email as needed. You could also consider a feature request on our issue tracker, which can be found here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to try [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/). Although it doesn't specifically have alerts for quota limits, you can probably set up other alerts to do the job (e.g. 500s caused by quota errors, or overall usage).

Comment: that's about as close as we can get, I guess